# diable display command output on screen?

Tags: unix, bash, echo

when i write bash the output appear on th screen ....i don't want to display the command and the command output on screen how i can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
somecommand &> /dev/null
```

Comment: thank you it is work ... but if you know how i can do this on windows CMD

Comment: `somecommand > NUL`, I think.

Comment: i try it but it is effect on the exit code (return value of the batch in windows)

Comment: @Osama: If you want to dump `stderr` as well as `stdout`, use something like `somecommand > NUL 2>&1` -- This will redirect console output but the command will still populate `%ERRORLEVEL%` with exit code.

Comment: @jscott: When was FD redirection added to cmd.exe?

Comment: @Ignacio: Good question, I don't know exactly when `cmd.exe` started supporting this. I found [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930) indicating support in NT 3.1.

Comment: Huh. Wonder why I never noticed it then.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can use `NUL` as in:

```
somecommand > NUL
```

(Please change the tags to reflect that this is actually a Windows, not unix/bash question)